# Add host during runtime execution w/o starting new play

Tags: ansible

Is it possible during Ansible execution to add another host in the play, without starting a new play?

I am aware of the [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module, but that requires the start of a new play to add the host, which is undesired.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to alter the `ansible_play_hosts` list during a play. Meanwhile, you should ground your question to an actual use case. I don't see how starting a new play can be a real constraint.

Comment: All variables defined during execution are lost when starting a new play.

Comment: You can easily workarround that with `set_fact`.

Comment: Oh? How is that possible then?

Comment: ??... by using `set_fact` when needed... an [mcve](/help/mcve) showing your exact problem would help. At this stage, one can only give very general and overflying advice.

Comment: I don not mind not stating my exact problem, as you answer already provides me with enough help.

Comment: The problem can't be clearer. See my answer. Preen the comments and the close status, please. Do not change and do not close the question. See the bug [#59401](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/59401). It was opened by an Ansible member. There is no activity and no comments. The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) doesn't mention how *refresh_inventory* influences the 'in-flight play'. It's a moving target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By design, it's not possible to add hosts to 'in-flight play'. Quoting from the Summary of Ansible bug [#59401](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/59401):

> By design, the in-flight play will not start running tasks on newly-added hosts, but it will stop running tasks on hosts that have disappeared. Newly-created hosts from an inventory refresh are immediately visible in ansible_play_hosts, even though they're not executing.

---

**Notes**

- The bug claims *refresh_inventory* and *add_host* should have the same effects.
- One might expect that the option [*refresh_inventory*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) of the module [*meta*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#ansible-builtin-meta-module-execute-ansible-actions) does the job. The scenario would be:

1. Start a play
2. Modify the source of the inventory
3. Run `- meta: refresh_inventory`

Unfortunately, the example of the INI file below shows that this doesn't work. The host *host03* is added to the inventory and to the list *ansible_play_hosts_all* as well. But, then, the following task *debug* doesn't run at this host. Play recap doesn't include this host either.

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[test]
host01
host02
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true

    - community.general.ini_file:
        path: hosts
        section: test
        option: "{{ item.host }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
        allow_no_value: true
      loop:
        - {host: host03, state: present}
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - meta: refresh_inventory

    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

PLAY [test] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - host01
  - host02

TASK [community.general.ini_file] ************************************************************
changed: [host01 -> localhost] => (item={'host': 'host03', 'state': 'present'})

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - host01
  - host02
  - host03

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  inventory_hostname: host01
ok: [host02] => 
  inventory_hostname: host02

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This is the solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, Kevin. Actually, it is not. I was too quick. See the updated answer.